# How can we maintain versioning in INFORMATICA using GitHub

Tags: git, version-control, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am new to Informatica ETL Tool and am into a new project. Our requirement is to setup github to maintain Informatica objects versioning. Can you please help me how can we setup Github for informatica and need step by step procedure if possible.

Thanks,
Sudha

Comment: Take a look at the following link to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What have you tried? What is not working? Have you been reading about GitHub? I guess Informatica artifacts won't be much different here from anything else, so if you have experience setting up GitHub, you should do fine. In case of issues, ask precise quesitons here - community will surely help!

Comment: Also, why not use informatica versioning? Its inbuilt version control system.